# Kendo Mobile - dataBinding not be called on listview

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have used the example code from the documentation:

```
<div data-role="view">
    <ul id="foo"></ul>
</div>

<script>
$("#foo").kendoMobileListView({
   dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [{title: "foo"}, {title: "bar"}]
   }),

  dataBinding: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

dataBinding function is not called. I then, instead, tested with a "dataBound" function and that does get called as expected.

I am using Kendo Mobile v2013.2.910 and jQuery 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI Mobile developer here. The dataBinding event is fresh off the oven – so fresh that it is yet to be available in the upcoming service pack release. It should not have slipped in the docs, I am sorry for that.

Comment: Too hot for these builds eh? Ha, no worries man - thanks for the heads up! This feature smells delicious.